# How to apply sklean pipeline to a list of features depending on availability

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 features (e.g., all floats). Given the different characteristics of the features (e.g., mean), the dataframe can be broken into 4 subsets: mean <0, mean within range (0,1), mean within range (1,100), mean >=100

For each subset, a different pipeline will be applied, however, they may not always be available, for example, the dataset might only contain mean <0; or it may contain only mean <0 and mean (1,100); or it may contain all 4 subsets

The question is how to apply the pipelines depending on the availability of the subsets.

The problem is that there will be total 7 different combinations:
all subset exists, only 3 exists, only 2 subset exists, only 1 subset exist.

How can I assign different pipelines depending on the availability of the subsets without using a nested if else (10 if/else)

```
if subset1 exists:
    make_column_transformer(pipeline1, subset1)
elif subset2 exists:
    make_column_transformer(pipeline2, subset2)
elif subset3 exists:
    make_column_transformer(pipeline3, subset3)
elif subset1 and subset 2 exists
    make_column_transformer([(pipeline1, subset1), (pipeline2, subset2)]
elif subset3 and subset 2 exists
    make_column_transformer([(pipeline3, subset3), (pipeline2, subset2)]
elif subset1 and subset 3 exists
    make_column_transformer([(pipeline1, subset1), (pipeline3, subset3)]
elif subset1 and subset2 and subset3 exists:
    make_column_transformer([(pipeline1, subset1), (pipeline2, subset2), (pipeline3, subset3)]
```

Is there a better way to avoid this nested if else (considering that if we have 10 different subsets *_*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to apply different transformations to different sets of features is by `ColumnTransformer` [1]. You could then have a lists with the column names, which can be filled based on the conditions you want. Then, each transformer will take the columns listed in each list, for example `cols_mean_lt0 = [...]`, etc.

Having said that, your approach doesn't look good to me. You probably want to scale the features so they all have the same mean and std. Depending on the algorithm you'll use, this may be mandatory or not.

[1] https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html

EDIT:

[ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) takes `transformers`, which are a tuple of name, tuple and columns. What you want is to have multiple transformers, each of which will process different columns. The columns in the tuple can be indicated by 'string or int, array-like of string or int, slice, boolean mask array or callable'. Here is where I suggest you pass a list of columns.

This way, you can have three transformers, one for each of your cases. Now, to indicate which columns you want each transformer to process, you just have to create three lists, one for each transformer. Each column will corresond to one of the lists. This is simple to to. In a loop you can check for each column what the mean is, and then append the column name to the list which corresponds to the corresponding transformer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. indeed i use make_column_transformer which is a shorthand for ColumnTransformer.

My question is irrelevant to the type of subsets (it can be 10 categorical features with each applied with a different pipeline, which end up to a long list of possibilities of combo of subsets). The question is how to dynamically call the transfomer depending on the availability of the subsets without using this big list of nested if else

Comment: Edited answer. I hope it is now clear how you could dynamically call the transfomer depending on the availability of the subsets without using this big list of nested if else.